# String replaceAll not replacing i++;

Tags: java, string, str-replace, replaceall

```
String preCode = "helloi++;world";
String newCode = preCode.replaceAll("i++;", "");
```

// Desired output :: `newCode = "helloworld";`

But this is not replacing i++ with blank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`

```
String preCode = "helloi++;world";
String newCode = preCode.replace("i++;", "");
```

or if you want `replaceAll()`, apply following regex

```
String preCode = "helloi++;world";
String newCode = preCode.replaceAll("i\\+\\+;", "");
```

Note : in the case of `replace()` the first argument is a character sequence, but in the case of `replaceAll` the first argument is regex

Comment: "this is helpfull if you have multiple occurances of character to be replaced" - The only difference between the two function is that one uses regex and the other uses string literals. Both their description starts with "Replaces each substring of this string that matches..."

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(java.lang.String)` will prevent you from making mistakes when converting a string literal to a regex.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have updated the answer now

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
 public class Practice {
 public static void main(String...args) {
 String preCode = "Helloi++;world";
 String newCode = preCode.replace(String.valueOf("i++;"),"");
 System.out.println(newCode);
}  
}
```

Comment: What would you need `String.valueOf("i++")` for? Just using `i++;` should be sufficient. Also you are missing the semicolon.

Comment: Or you could do `"i++;".toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the string that you are using to replace , that is cnsidered as regex pattern to skip the meaning you will have to use escape sequence like below.

```
String newCode = preCode.replaceAll("i\\+\\+;", "");
```